# Std Pair Initialization

Tags: c++, standard-library, std-pair

This is my first time working with pairs, totally confused. 
How to initialize a pair as to insert it in the map?
Should I include some standard library for this?

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class Roads
{  
 public:  
  map< pair<string,string>, int > Road_map; 
  void AddRoad( string s, string d )
       { int b = 2 ; Road_map.insert( pair<s,d>, b) ; }  //pair<s,d> is wrong here.

 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::make_pair`:

```
Road_map[make_pair(s, d)] = b;
```

Alternatively, you can construct an `std::pair` like so:

```
Road_map[pair<string,string>(s,d)] = b;
```

The `std::make_pair` approach saves you having to name the types of `s` and `d`.

Notice that the appropriate function here is `operator[]` and not `insert`. `std::map::insert` takes a single argument which is a `std::pair` containing the key and value you want to insert. You would have to do that like this:

```
Road_map.insert(pair<const pair<string,string>, int>(make_pair(s, d), b);
```

You can make this a bit prettier with `typedef`:

```
typedef map<pair<string,string>, int> map_type;
Road_map.insert(map_type::value_type(map_type::key_type(s, d), b));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::make_pair` instead. Like so:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Roads
{  
 public:  
    map< pair<string,string>, int > Road_map; 
    void AddRoad( string s, string d )
    { 
        int b = 2 ; 
        Road_map[make_pair(s,d)] = b; 
    }

 };
```

Comment: Am I going crazy or will this not work because `insert` is supposed to take a single argument of `value_type` (pair with key and value)? There's no `insert` that takes key and value arguments.

Comment: This didn't work. It gave the following error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::const_iterator' 
What should I use in this case ?

Comment: @sftrabbit you are correct. Interestingly enough I didn't look at it enough.

Comment: @Ever Yeah, I thought so. It's trying to call the two argument version of `insert` which takes a `const_iterator` and some value.

Comment: @sftrabbit Okay, what should I use in this case ? Is there an alternative for insert?

Comment: @Ever look at my edit. You can use `myMap[key] = value;` syntax. Just like other answers have provided.

Answer (score 1):

For a `map<K, T>`, the `value_type` is actually `pair<K const, T>`. However, the easiest way to access this is by using typedefs:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> string_pair;
typedef std::map<string_pair, int>             map_type;

// ...

Road_map.insert(map_type::value_type(map_type::key_type(s, d), b));
```

In C++11 you can use the easier `emplace` interface:

```
Road_map.emplace(map_type::key_type(s, d), b);
```